# What's the difference between size_t and int in C++?

Tags: c++, c, types, integer, size-t

In several C++ examples I see a use of the type `size_t` where I would have used a simple `int`. What's the difference, and why `size_t` should be better?

Comment: For an actual example where they aren't interchangeable, see a question I asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645168/how-to-write-a-stdbitset-template-that-works-on-32-and-64-bit

Answer (score 177, accepted):

From [the friendly Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t#Member_data_types):

> The stdlib.h and stddef.h header files define a datatype called **size_t** which is used to represent the size of an object. Library functions that take sizes expect them to be of type size_t, and the sizeof operator evaluates to size_t.
>
> The actual type of size_t is platform-dependent; a common mistake is to assume size_t is the same as unsigned int, which can lead to programming errors, particularly as 64-bit architectures become more prevalent.

Also, check [Why size_t matters](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/Why-size-t-matters)

Comment: And so, what is size_t?

Comment: @NDEthos It depends! On this here Linux `/usr/include/stdlib.h` gets the definition from `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/stddef.h` and therein it defaults to `long unsigned int` unless some other header file says otherwise.

Comment: I confirm [size_t to int tuncation is dangerous](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-2315). This might be off‑topic, but how to write a patch alone to fix that kind of mistakes when it occurs thousands times in the linux kernel ?

Answer (score 62):

`size_t` **1)** is the data type used to represent sizes (as its name implies) and **2)** is platform (and even potentially implementation) dependent, so it should be used ***only*** for representing sizes.

Representing a size, `size_t` is naturally unsigned (can you have a box that is negative 3 meters wide?). Many `stdlib` functions, including `malloc`, `sizeof`, and various string operation functions use `size_t` as a datatype.

An `int` is signed by default, and even though its size is also platform dependent, it will be a fixed 32bits on most modern machine (and though `size_t` is 64 bits on any 64-bit architecture, `int` *remains* 32 bits long on those same 64-bit architectures).

**Summary**: Use `size_t` to represent the size of an object and `int` (or `long`) in other cases. Be aware that `size_t` is unsigned while both `int` and `long` are signed by default (unless prepended with `unsigned` , or modified to `uint` or `ulong`).

Answer (score 19):

The `size_t` type is defined as the unsigned integral type of the `sizeof` operator.  In the real world, you will often see `int` defined as 32 bits (for backward compatibility) but `size_t` defined as 64 bits (so you can declare arrays and structures more than 4 GiB in size) on 64-bit platforms.  If a `long int` is also 64-bits, this is called the LP64 convention; if `long int` is 32 bits but `long long int` and pointers are 64 bits, that’s LLP64. You also might get the reverse, a program that uses 64-bit instructions for speed, but 32-bit pointers to save memory.  Also, `int` is signed and `size_t` is unsigned.

There were historically a number of other platforms where addresses were wider or shorter than the native size of `int`.  In fact, in the ’70s and early  ’80s, this was more common than not: all the popular 8-bit microcomputers had 8-bit registers and 16-bit addresses, and the transition between 16 and 32 bits also produced many machines that had addresses wider than their registers.  I occasionally still see questions here about Borland Turbo C for MS-DOS, whose Huge memory mode had 20-bit addresses stored in 32 bits on a 16-bit CPU (but which could support the 32-bit instruction set of the 80386); the Motorola 68000 had a 16-bit ALU with 32-bit registers and addresses; there were IBM mainframes with 15-bit, 24-bit or 31-bit addresses.  You also still see different ALU and address-bus sizes in embedded systems.

Any time `int` is smaller than `size_t`, and you try to store the size or offset of a very large file or object in an `unsigned int`, there is the possibility that it could overflow and cause a bug.  With an `int`, there is also the possibility of getting a negative number. If an `int` or `unsigned int` is wider, the program will run correctly but waste memory.

You should generally use the correct type for the purpose if you want portability.  A lot of people will recommend that you use signed math instead of unsigned (to avoid nasty, subtle bugs like `1U < -3`).  For that purpose, the standard library defines `ptrdiff_t` in `<stddef.h>` as the signed type of the result of subtracting a pointer from another.

That said, a workaround might be to bounds-check all addresses and offsets against `INT_MAX` and either `0` or `INT_MIN` as appropriate, and turn on the compiler warnings about comparing signed and unsigned quantities in case you miss any.  You should always, always, always be checking your array accesses for overflow in C anyway.

Answer (score 8):

It's because size_t can be anything other than an int (maybe a struct). The idea is that it decouples it's job from the underlying type.

Comment: I think size_t is actually guaranteed to be an aliased for an unsigned integer, so it can't be a structure. I don't have a reference handy to back this up right now, though.

Comment: @danio Why is it so?can you explain?

Comment: I wouldn't link to cplusplus if I was you! If you can't quote chapter, verse, paragraph and line then it is all just hearsay! :-)

Comment: `size_t` is specified as an **unsigned integer** type. C11 §6.5.3.4 5 "The value of the result of both operators (`sizeof` `_Alignof`) is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`,".

Answer (score -3):

The definition of `SIZE_T` is found at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441980.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230394.aspx

**Pasting here the required information:**

`SIZE_T` is a `ULONG_PTR` representing the maximum number of bytes to which a pointer can point.

This type is declared as follows:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;
```

A `ULONG_PTR` is an unsigned long type used for pointer precision. It is used when casting a pointer to a long type to perform pointer arithmetic.

This type is declared as follows:

```
typedef unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR;
```

Comment: `SIZE_T` isn't `size_t`, what the OP asked about.

Comment: That’s a Microsoft extension, not part of the standard language.

Comment: `SIZE_T` is totally different from `size_t`. You can't declare a variable of type `SIZE_T`.