# Why can't gcc deduce templated size for array argument? (C++11)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11

**The following code gives a compiler error (gcc-4.7 run with `-std=c++11`):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, int N>
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, const std::array<T, N> & arr) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<N-1; ++i)
    os << arr[i] << " ";
  os << arr[i];
  return os;
}

int main() {
  std::array<double, 2> lower{1.0, 1.0};
  std::cout << lower << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Error message:**

> tmp6.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: tmp6.cpp:16:16: error: cannot bind
>   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to
>   ‘std::basic_ostream&&’ In file included from
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40:0,
>                    from tmp6.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:600:5: error:
>     initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp = std::array]’

When I get rid of the template function declaration and replace `T` with `double` and `N` with `2`, it compiles just fine (**edit: leaving `T` and replacing `N` with 2 works, but specifying `N=2` as the default argument for `N` doesn't work.**).

1. Does anyone know why gcc can't automatically bind this?
2. <del>What would be the syntax for calling the `<<` operator with explicitly specified template parameters?</del>

**Answer to question 2:** `operator<<<double, 2>(std::cout, lower);`

**Edit:** This is also true for the following function, which is only templated in the array size:

```
template <int N>
void print(const std::array<double, N> & arr) {
  std::cout << "print array here" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::array<double, 2> lower{1.0, 1.0};
  print<2>(lower); // this works
  print(lower);    // this does NOT work
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be defining `operator <<` for a standard type.

Comment: @K-ballo Any idea how to answer either of the two numbered questions in the post?

Comment: If I could answer, I would have placed an answer instead of a comment... The problem probably comes from implementing operators in a wrong way.

Comment: @K-ballo The same question could be proposed using a function `template <int N> print (const std::array<double, N> & arr) { /*...*/ }`. I wonder why gcc can't bind this...

Comment: Do you mean `print( lower );` won't compile? Could you add your test case for the `print` version to your question?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/645273/34509

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider your declaration:

```
template <typename T, int N>
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, const std::array<T, N> & arr) {
```

The definition for `std::array` is:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> class array {...};
```

You are using `int` instead of `std::size_t`, and that's why it doesn't *match*.

Comment: Huge +1. Thanks a lot, I'm not sure I *ever* would have found that.

Comment: +1 I was just reading what standard (14.8.2) says about template deduction and wondered what I've omitted, because there was nothing against this kind of deduction. The incorrect type in the template definition catched me too.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `operator<<` with specified template parameters in this, not so aestethic, way:

```
operator<< <double,2>(std::cout, lower) << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 I don't know why I didn't just try that-- I was so hung up on the `<<<` that I didn't think the compiler would like it (I guess I was projecting)!