# Size of short, int, long, float, double long, double, char

Tags: c, sizeof

I want to find out the (short / int / long / float / double / long double / char) size, so I wrote this code:

```
printf("short\t\t%d\n", sizeof(short));    
printf("int\t\t%d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("long\t\t%d\n", sizeof(long));
printf("float\t\t%d\n", sizeof(float));
printf("double\t\t%d\n", sizeof(double));  
printf("long double\t%d\n", sizeof(long double));    
printf("char\t\t%d\n", sizeof(char));
```

BUT 
the output is:

```
type            bytes
short           512
int             512
long            1024
float           1024
double          1024
long double     1024
char            256
```

Why are the number of bytes so large?

Shouldn't it be 2, 8, ...?

Comment: you are right, it usually should... what is the context you are running this in? first of all language (assuming C), compiler, hardware, etc.

Comment: That is strange.  What OS, compiler, etc?

Comment: For what it's worth, everything is getting left shifted by 8 bits...

Comment: Added C tag, feel free to correct this if it's incorrect.

Comment: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.  So `%d` is not appropriate.

Comment: And you think the implicit conversion from `size_t` to `int` is multiplying by 256? Why would that happen?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Anything could happen.

Comment: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’

Comment: @Dan: Using `%d` to print a `size_t` does not create an implicit conversion from `size_t` to `int`. At best, it reinterprets the bytes of a `size_t` as an `int`. At worst, it bolluxes the stack because the platform ABI has been violated, which can result in further misbehavior by a program, an immediate crash, or other undesired effects.

Comment: @Oleg Olivson  Argument 2 is type `size_t`.  C11 6.5.3.4 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` evaluates to a `size_t`, not an `int`.  So `%d` is not appropriate; you're invoking undefined behaviour.

To correctly print data of type `size_t`, I suggest e.g. `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(float));`, etc.

Comment: Or better, use `%zu` for `size_t`. In theory, undefined behavior could cause any problem, but I doubt that's the root problem as I can't reproduce the problem with `%d`.

Comment: Related - [What's the difference between size_t and int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-size-t-and-int-in-c).

Answer (score -1):

Use : format specifier long unsigned int. it will work fine.
Ex:
printf("sizeof(long double)= %**lu**\n",  sizeof(long double));

Ans:16

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the accepted answer and is in fact wrong. There is no guarantee that `%lu` is a correct format specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, can you correct me here ? I will remove my answer once you provide me the solution.

Comment: `size_t` may be an alias for any unsigned type that has at least 16 bits. That is, it may be `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`. On "exotic" implementations it may even be `unsigned char`! When calling a function without a prototype, or a variadic function like `printf` that does not prototype its variadic arguments, you must guarantee that the *actual* type of the argument matches the type the function expects the argument to be; `%lu` is not the right format specifier unless `size_t` happens to be `unsigned long`. In C99 and later, `%zu` always works.

Comment: [This question and its answers have more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33648596)