# Is this a bug in glibc printf?

Tags: c, printf, glibc, stdio, stdint

Using `stdint.h` from glibc (gcc SUSE Linux version 9.2.1, Intel Core I7 processor) I came across a most strange behaviour when printing `INT32_MIN` directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", INT16_MIN);
    int a = INT16_MIN;
    printf("%d\n", a);

    printf("%ld\n", INT32_MIN);
    long b = INT32_MIN;
    printf("%ld\n", b);

    printf("%ld\n", INT64_MIN);
    long c = INT64_MIN;
    printf("%ld\n", c);
}
```

which outputs:

```
-32768
-32768
2147483648
-2147483648
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
```

Furthermore, if I try

```
printf("%ld\n", -INT32_MIN);
```

I get the same result, but with compiler `warning: integer overflow in expression '-2147483648' of type 'int' results in '-2147483648' [-Woverflow]`.

Not that this is incredibly bad for any existing program, actually it seems pretty harmless, but is this a bug in good old printf?

Comment: But it works when I print from `long b`, also there's the compiler warning, which still persists when using `%d` for `INT32_MIN`.

Comment: Ah, ok, you guys are right, it's weird, but its undefined per standard, the `%d` works fine, thanks!

Comment: Note that `-INT32_MIN` is undefined behavior too: signed integer overflow.

Comment: PSA: For a modern compiler, "it's weird" and "it's undefined" are pretty much synonymous.

Comment: @NateEldredge: great, thanks! This completes the explanation provided in the answer below, on why the compiler raises an overflow warning but results in the same value: `-INT32_MIN` overflows up from -2,147,483,468 to +2,147,483,468, which warps again to -2,147,483,468, and is thus printed +2,147,483,468, according to Eric's answer below :)

Comment: Although not a standard-required diagnostic, every gcc I've used for at least a decade warns when (constant) format specifier doesn't match the data; for your line with INT32_MIN I get `format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`. This should have been enough to tell you that INT32 is int not long, and printing an int value with a long format isn't safe.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, thanks for checking, mine is gcc (SUSE Linux) 9.2.1 20190820, and I don't get that warning _unless_ I specify it explicitly, probably it's a setting on my profile or else, in any case you are right, that warning should be enabled for all compilations. Will review my makefiles now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug in glibc printf?

No.

> `printf("%ld\n", INT32_MIN);` … `2147483648`

There is an easy way for this to happen. The second integer/pointer argument to a function should be passed in 64-bit register RCX. `INT32_MIN` is a 32-bit `int` with bit pattern 0x80000000, since that is the two’s complement pattern for −2,147,483,648. The rules for passing a 32-bit value in a 64-bit register are that it is passed in the low 32 bits, and the high bits are not used by the called routine. For this call, 0x80000000 was put into the low 32 bits, and the high bits happened to be set to zero.

Then `printf` examines the format string and expects a 64-bit `long`. So it goes looking in RCX for a 64-bit integer. Of course, the rules for passing a 64-bit integer are to use the entire register, so `printf` takes all 64 bits, 0x0000000080000000. That is the bit pattern for +2,147,483,468, so `printf` prints `2147483648`.

Of course, the C standard does not define the behavior, so other things could happen, but this is a likely scenario for what did happen in the instance you observed.

> `printf("%d\n", INT16_MIN);` … `-32768`

Since `int` is 32 bits in your C implementation, the `int16_t` value `INT16_MIN` is automatically promoted to `int` for the function call, so this passes an `int`, and `%d` expects an `int`, so there is no mismatch, and the correct value is printed.

Similarly, the other `printf` calls in the question have arguments that match the conversion specifications (given the particular definitions of `int16_t` and such in your C implementation; they could mismatch in others), so their values are printed correctly.

Comment: "and the high bits happened to be set to zero.": Which, for OP's information,  is particularly likely, since most instructions that would populate the low 32 bits (`ECX`) have the side effect of zeroing the high 32 bits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6

Comment: Fantastic... that would never have occurred to me: the compiler parses the `INT32_MAX` contents in the context of a 32-bit integer (since no `L` or `LL` modifiers specified) and generates the bit pattern you mentioned, but stores it unconverted to a 64-bit register (since no one ever specified what it should do in that case), which in this particular case results in just the absolute (positive) value of the (negative) original. Explains why the other cases worked fine, and this particular one did not. A lesson learned on the subtleties of 'undefined behaviour', thanks for the fine answer.

Comment: In my comment above I meant `INT32_MIN`, not `INT32_MAX`.

Comment: To complete the answer, @NateEldredge provided a comment on my question explaining `-INT32_MIN` is also undefined behaviour, and thus explains the overflow warning but with same print result: `-INT32_MIN` is -(-2,147,483,468) = +2,147,483,468, which warps to -2,147,483,468, and is thus printed +2,147,483,468 according to your answer.

Comment: As commented above, compiler warning `-Wformat` should be enabled, as it flags this conversion issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's observe this specific snippet

```
    long a = INT32_MIN;
    printf("%ld\n", a);          // #1
    printf("%ld\n", INT32_MIN);  // #2
```

It prints the following (as per your example, I haven't tried it myself, it's implementation dependent, as I'll note later):

```
-2147483648
2147483648
```

Now, in #1 we are passing a `long` to `printf`. The function works with a variadic argument list and based on the format specified, the value of our parameter will be interpreted as a `signed long`, and thus we end up with the value `-2147483648`.

For #2 we have a somewhat different situation. If you look at how `INT32_MIN` is defined, you'll see that it's a plain old C macro, for example:

```
# define INT32_MIN      (-2147483647-1)
```

so, our line

```
printf("%ld\n", INT32_MIN);
```

is actually

```
printf("%ld\n", (-2147483647-1));
```

Where the argument type isn't a long, but an integer (see [this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407498/2367906))! Compare it to this

```
    int b = INT32_MIN;
    printf("%ld\n", b);
```

And it prints out the same value you observed (positive).

Now it boils down to what your question should actually be:

> What happens when `printf` receives a value of a type that isn't in the format specifier?

[Undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648596/why-are-arguments-which-do-not-match-the-conversion-specifier-in-printf-undefine)!

Comment: Ah, ok, you guys are right, it's weird, but its undefined per standard, the `%d` works fine, thanks!

Comment: `printf` in `printf("%ld\n", a);` does not accept a `void *`, nor is there one in the arguments.

Comment: My bad, I wrongly assumed variadic arguments would be interpreted as void* and the function impl would be responsible for the interpretation.