# Problem with autoconf not making gcc with -Wall warnings

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, autoconf, automake

I have a simple project with a simple `configure.ac` script:

```
AC_INIT(...)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES(...)
AC_OUTPUT
```

using GNU Autoconf version 2.69 (OpenSUSE Linux with gcc 9.2.1), but gcc is being called with no warning flags:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -g -O2 -MT aprog.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/aprog.Tpo -c -o aprog.o aprog.c
mv ...
gcc  -g -O2   -o aprog aprog.o -lgmp
```

In particular, I found `-Wformat` [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041658/is-this-a-bug-in-glibc-printf#comment123818781_70041658). Shouldn't `-Wall` include `-Wformat`? And shouldn't all warnings appear on the make line? If I run gcc line directly with `-Wformat` the warning shows in compile but it doesn't when I run `autoconf`, `configure` and `make`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Wall` flag in the `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(...)` invocation refers to warnings from automake and related tools like aclocal, not to compiler warnings. You will see these warnings when you are running `autoreconf`.

Note that while you ***can*** also add `-Werror` to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(...)` to make your `autoreconf` run fail on warnings, many common macros (like those shipped with gettext or libtool) will still use deprecated macros which generates a warning, so `-Werror` means you cannot use this standard set of tools, so `-Werror` is not very useful in many cases.

If you want to add compiler options, there are a third party macros (e.g. `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG`) which test whether the compiler recognizes a given compile option and you can then add them to some variable and use that in places. That is a different stackoverflow question, though.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'm not quite acquainted to autotools.  So, my guess is I should specify `-Wall` gcc option in the `Makefile.am`, like in `AM_CPPFLAGS`?