# What can fix the for-loop error this hash function is throwing?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, hashtable

I am making a multiplicative string hash function and my for-loop is throwing an error. I am attempting to iterate through each character in the string value by using its length.

The error:
`hashtable.cpp:29:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare] for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)`

Hash function:

```
int HashTable::Hash(string key)
{
    int hash = 5381; //initial value

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)  //line that is causing error
    {
        hash = (hash * 33) + (int)key[i];

    }               

    return hash % size;

}
```

Is there another way to write my condition statement to avoid this error?

Comment: change `int i` to `size_t i`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I would ask what size_t does but I will look around for that answer.

Comment: Glad it helped :) For the new question, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-size-t-and-int-in-c)

Comment: What you are calling an 'error' is not a compiler report about an error.  Note the word 'warning: ' after the '.cpp:29:20:".  Please google and review "what is the difference between a compiler warning and an error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned. Mixing signed (`i`) with unsigned (`key.length()`) is problematic so this is what the error is about.

You can:

- use `std::size_t i`
- use `static_cast<int>(key.length())`
- better yet use range for `for (auto ch : key)`