# Storing strlen(str) to n integer gives different output than using it as it is in a for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, integer, strlen

In the code, if we use an integer n to store strlen(str), the output by for loop becomes different than used here! Why is that happening?

void helper(char str[], int start){

```
int n=strlen(str)
if(str[start]=='\0'||str[start]=='\0')
    return;

helper(str,start+1);

if(str[start]=='p' && str[start+1]=='i'){
    for(int i=n;i>=start+2;i--){
        str[i+2]=str[i];
    }   
str[start]='3';
str[start+1]='.';
str[start+2]='1';
str[start+3]='4';
}
```

}

Comment: You need to show both versions of the code. You need to show how the output is different in both cases. You need to show how you are calling this function. It's very hard to answer a question when all you do is dump some code and ask what is wrong with it.

Comment: Probably you have undefined behaviour somewhere. If `n` equals `strlen(str)` then this code `for(int i=n;i>=start+2;i--){ str[i+2]=str[i];` is probably an error since `str[i+2]` would be an out of bounds array access. That **might** be the explaination for what you are seeing but without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-size-t-and-int-in-c

Comment: possibly because the function `helper` changes the string? and therefore its length changes?

Comment: `if(str[start]=='\0' || str[start]=='\0')` This is checking the same `str[start]` twice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete your question, you should include your expected output and the one you got. Or the difference that you observe.
Anyway, it seems that your code contains undefined behaviour / out of bond array access.

```
for(int i=n;i>=start+2;i--){
        str[i+2]=str[i];
}
```

If n is the size of the string, then at the first loop iteration, i+2 is greater than the string size.

Please complete your question to get more details.